# Calculating success probability variance using Monte Carlo simulation

Tags: probability, monte-carlo

For a Monte Carlo simulation where each sample can produce a success value (1) or a failure value (0), what is the variance of the probability for success?

Given n samples and r successes, the estimated probability for a success is $\frac{r}{n}$.
What is the variance of the probability for a success?

Comment: This is basically a Bernoulli process, so the variance of r is $\sigma^{2} = \frac{rq}{p^{2}}$.

Comment: I would suggest the maximum-likelihood-estimate.

Comment: Can you elaborate? I read about maximum-likelihood-estimate, but could not figure out how to calculate the variance.

Comment: Unfortunately not, but you should find formulas in the internet.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to solve this.
This is a Bernoulli process. The number of trials needed to get r has a negative binomial distribution NB(r, p): $\mu_{n}=\frac{r}{p} ; \sigma_{n}=\frac{r(1-p)}{p^{2}}$

Extracting p and propagating the error, we get: $p=\frac{r}{\mu_{n}} ; \sigma_{p}=\frac{p^{2}(1-p)}{r}$